# Unable to report Facebook install event

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to report install events to Facebook through Android, using the call to:

```
com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(<context>, <appId>);
```

In DDMS, I see the following request was sent:

```
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871): Request:
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   Id:  2
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   URL: https://graph.facebook.com/<app id appears here>/activities?format=json&sdk=android&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121026
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   Method:  POST
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   User-Agent:  FBAndroidSDK.3.0.1
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   Content-Type:    multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   Parameters:
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):       format:  json
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):       sdk: android
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):       migration_bundle:    fbsdk:20121026
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):   Attachments:
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):       attribution: 9201d8b6-2c14-47e1-b326-0c397a9498d0
02-23 21:02:30.205: D/FacebookSDK.Request(4871):       event:   MOBILE_APP_INSTALL
```

And the following response is received:

```
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871): Response (raw)
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871):   Size: 4
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871):   Response:
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871): true
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871): Response
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871):   Id: 3
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871):   Size: 4
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871):   Responses:
02-23 21:02:31.265: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4871): [{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":true}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}]
```

However, I see no mention of this activation in Facebook's dashboard in the AppEvents tab, or in the Mobile App Installs tab.

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.0.1, the Facebook App is installed and logged-in on the Android device that I'm testing.

Furthermore, I can see iOS activations just fine.

Any solution for this issue, which doesn't require me to upgrade the Facebook SDK to the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow up, I can update that I had updated the Facebook SDK to version 3.7.0 and replaced 'publishInstallAsync' with the newer 'activateApp' method.

This has fixed the issue for me.